# Balances Via RPC

Tags: json-rpc, balance

I'm trying to get some wallet info via RPC commands.
`getunconfirmedbalance` gives me the "Pending" amount in the GUI wallet.

What does `getbalance` give me? Is that value the "Available" value in the GUI wallet, or the "Total" value?

Whichever it gives me, I can then add or subtract the pending value to get the *other* value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `getbalance` give me?

`getbalance` returns the total available balance according to your configuration. If you have `-spendzeroconfchange` set to `1` (the default), this is your total confirmed + unconfirmed balance.

> Whichever it gives me, I can then add or subtract the pending value to get the other value.

By default `getbalance - getunconfirmedbalance = confirmed_balance`.

---

PS: This information is available from the `help` and the manpage, which I merely quoted..